# Install version of F#

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017

I have had to rebuild my machine and with that I have reinstalled visual studio 2017.
This is done through the installer and results in f# 4.5 installed.

All my current solutions are using 4.3.1.0.
How do I install this version as I cannot updated csproj file at this time?

Looking at this link(https://fsharp.org/use/windows/), I do say a way to specify a version

This is the error in output:

```
: error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Users\nmcgrath\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_bd0c15bd\devenv.exe.config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.  D:\scm\product\mcm\src\----\-----.fsproj
```

The following is fsprog file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>c4a987bd-7240-465c-b046-6f10df0fd8f4</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>CCS.MCM.Data</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CCS.MCM.Data</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <TargetFSharpCoreVersion>4.3.1.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>
    <Name>CCS.MCM.Data</Name>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <Tailcalls>false</Tailcalls>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\CCS.MCM.Data.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <Tailcalls>true</Tailcalls>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\CCS.MCM.Data.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Types.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Repository.fs" />
    <Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="CCS.Common">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\CCS\CCS.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion)\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MongoDB.Bson">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\mongo\MongoDB.Bson.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MongoDB.Driver">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\mongo\MongoDB.Driver.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\mongo\MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

And when I do a build in VS2017 or 2019 the following is output

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CCS.MCM.Data, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets(155,9): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\fsc.exe" is invalid.
1>Done building project "CCS.MCM.Data.fsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The fsc.exe is not in this location.
I copied in file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0 to see if it would work but is did not("fsc.exe" exited with code -532462766)

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: You should be able to use VS 2017 with F# 4.5 to work with projects that are using version 4.3.1.0. Do you get any errors when you open the projects and try to build them?

Comment: Tomas Updated with output error. Does this mean I need to install an older SDK?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to install an older F#, since it is backwards compatible. Your old could should load and build, including against newer FSharp.Core versions. Have you tried VS 2019?

Comment: Updated question with more detail, cant figure out how to get working, I need to keep at solution on 4.3.1.0 as we are not in position to upgrade right now

Comment: Use only VS 2019, as already suggested. Then take it from there.